# Проверить SAS-диски на bad'ы

Tags: raid, sas

столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть сервер с рейд-контроллером AVAGO LSI Megaraid, к нему подключена корзина с хардами. Нужно проверить как-то эти харды Викторией или HDDScan, не важно.
Проблема возникаем с тем, что софт не видит эти харды через рейд-контроллер и я не знаю, как до них добраться. Пробовал через LiveCD с вышеуказанным софтом и подсовыванием драйверов для рейд-контроллера, пробовал и с установкой OS и MegaRAID Storage Manager сверху, у меня ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге просто сделал RAID 0 на каждом отдельном харде и прогнал hddscan-ом из под ОС